# How to pass a parameter to a class scope fixture

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

Lets say I have a fixture like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def some_fixture(some_paramaters):
    do_something
    yield
    do_something
```

And i want to use it in this way:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('some_fixtures')
class TestSomething:
    code....
```

Is it possible to pass the parameter some_paramter using @pytest.mark.usefixtures decorator. Or is there any way to pass that parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this by using an autouse fixture.

```
import pytest
import requests

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def some_fixture(some_parameters):
    do_something
    yield
    do_something


class TestSomething:

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _calling_method(self, some_fixture):
    self._response = some_fixture(some_parameters)
```